# Smallest-circle problem, but with circles instead of points?

Tags: circles, packing-problem

I have a growing set of circles (and locations for those circles), each step I add one. I also need the smallest circle that contains all of the circles in my set. I found the wikipedia page about the [smallest-circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) and it states that there is a linear-time recursive algorithm that solves this, which would be perfect for my problem. The page however does not give the algorithm, and I couldn't find it either.

So my first question is, what's this smallest-circle algorithm called? Secondly, my problem is a little more complex, because I have circles rather than points. So any ideas on how it could be adapted to work with circles?

Comment: [This paper by Bernd Gärtner](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gaertner/texts/own_work/esa99_final.pdf) mentions "David White, who was developing code for the more general problem of finding the smallest ball enclosing balls". But the link in the paper is broken...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is called *Smallest enclosing ball of balls*.

For code, see [miniball](http://miniball.sourceforge.net) and [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Bounding_volumes/classCGAL_1_1Min__sphere__of__spheres__d.html).

The code mentioned above works in general dimension. There may be something simpler for dimension 2.

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at it, and it's far come complex than I though. Do you perhaps know of a java implementation of this? I've been searching but can't really find one (many for the enclosing ball of points though). A simple 2D implementation is enough.

Comment: @TheOddler, I don't know any implementation in java, sorry.

Comment: A shame. Thanks anyway! I'll have too look around some more then.